# Strange shape of flowing Streamlined Water. ( I think it is somewhat related to Fluid Dynamics and Force )

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

Before i proceed to my question, I want the reader of this question to try out this little experiment at home.

Take a cup or mug filled with water ( does not depend how much you fill the cup or the mug ). Start pouring the water out of the cup very slowly ( as much slow as you can, but make sure the pouring of water is continuous and it does not travel along the side of the cup while pouring it ) , and as you might guess, you will get a Streamlined flow of water near the point of the cup from where the water starts falling down. Now, place your finger on the path of the Streamlined Water Flow. I bet you will get to see the Streamlined motion of water **near your finger** get somewhat like a Pattern ( a bit continuous 'S' shaped ), as if the " line " of the water was being compressed !

You can also try out this experiment by turning the Basin knob to the least amount ( before the water starts to fall in drops instead of flowing in a streamlined way ) and then place ANY object ( literally anything, it can even be like, you have a cup, with Brimming water and you place the top surface of the water near the tap of the basin from where the water is flowing and you will still get to see the effect ( i.e. the deformation of the streamlined flow of the water ) above the surface of the water where the Streamlined flow of Water from the basin is touching the water surface in the cup ) in the PATH of the STREAMLINE FLOW of the water, you get to see the same effect.

I just wanted to ask if anyone can account for how this phenomenon takes place, and what are the forces involved that is causing such a **pattern** of the flowing water .  Also it will be helpful if you provide any mathematical data ( if any ) with the answer.

Thanks !!

Comment: Hope you will get to see the pattern I am trying to refer to.

Comment: can you please add the picture since all of us might not get to see what you want us to see ?

Comment: Ok I will try to give it in a few days, I actually I am a new user so I need to see first how to upload an image and then i will give it.